Timepicker is adding the time zone to the input date
The bootstrap timepicker is passing data that looks like this:
"Mon Jan 01 0001 17:00:02 GMT-0456 (Eastern Standard Time)"
When passed to the api, the string is cast to the C# datetime type except that the time is changed from 5pm to another time due to the GMT-0456 time zone data in the string. Here is after saving to the database: "0001-01-03 09:56:10.0000000" How can I ensure that the time remains the same as the user inputs in the UI (5PM)?
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Ftimepicker

The DateTime constructor sets the date to 1/1/01.  Your date is 1/1/01 + 17 hours and 2 seconds.  Then what is being saved is 1/1/01 + 57 hours 56 minutes and 10 seconds.  This is not a timezone issue since the day is being change by more than 48 hours.  Never save a DateTime to a string to solve this type of issue.  Best solution is always keeps the DateTime in GMT which is the way the date number is stored in the memory.  The ToString() method will automatically convert the GMT to the local timezone.

I'm not saving DateTime to string. The component sends data in that format to the the service layer on the client app. It looks ok at this point, then when the data is sent to the api the DateTime changes from the user inputted value. There is no manipulation of format currently

No.  Most drivers send a DateTime object.  Then DateTime is being displayed as a string using Culture Setting of the machine unless you are changing the object in your code.

The solution was to take given datetime, convert it to a string, parse out the time from that string, create a new date using the hours and minutes retrieved from prior, and then format that newly created date into ISO 8601 format. Then pass this new date into the api instead of the one that is created by the timepicker.

Store UTC dates on the database that will solve your issue so that every value of date in the database is in UTC time.
This has the additional advantage that anyone in the world can use your application.
Converting Local Time to UTC - SO Answer
